# How to install jdk 6 and 8

Tags: java-8, centos6

I was told that i can have multiple versions of java on my centos server. I need java 8 for new version of red5 and I need 6 for xuggle can someone tell me how to install both? I'm using centos 6.6 
Uhm I did research befor I asked! http://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/ and https://superuser.com/questions/388840/install-sun-java-6-and-sun-java-7-side-by-side-on-linux-fedora-16-using-rpm, there is no updated info! Now will someone help?

Comment: Is your problem with getting hold of the two install files (RPM or binary) or are you afraid that the installations may affect each other?

Comment: I don't know how to install without messing up

Comment: What I would do: list the contents of `*.tar.gz` or `*.rpm` before install to check what may become overwritten. Chances are that you may find version-specific paths in both cases (e.g. `jre1.8.0_31/README`), i.e. several versions of Java won't interfere (at the level of the file system, at least).

Answer (score 0):

You can install multiple versions of Java but you can only use one at a time.

Depending on your repositories you can install available version with `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk`, or any other available version.

To list available versions do `yum list available | grep -i jdk`.

To verify active version do `java -version`.

To change the active Java version you can use `alternatives --config java` and then chose the pretended version.